# Change UITableViewCell height in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCells` that are filled in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method with `UILabels` etc.
I'd like to change the height of the UITableViewCell, after I added the UILabels to the cell.
How can I do this? 
I read a lot about doing it in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, but this one is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so the new custom height is unknown when the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

So how can I set the height of my `UITableViewCell` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Thanks in advance, wasted lots of time on this one.

Comment: How are you labels frames are you giving?

Comment: yeah height of the row must be known before creating it. one way is this you save your height in an array after calculating how many labels will be in particular row and then loading the tableview

Comment: check this link:http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can change the contentView of a UITableViewCell, that works fine :) If I change that height in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function and call `[tableView beginUpdates]` right after, it changes well.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you solve your problem? i am having the same problem

Comment: Changing the height of the contentview calls heightForCell again, where I return a stored value for the cell height (so yes, it works, and it has stopped the insanity of code repeat in the app) thanks

Comment: You can refresh the related cell instead of all the tableview by this way :     [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Answer (score 7):

you can't change the height in cellForRowAtIndexPath. The tableView has to know the height before it displays the whole tableView. That's why `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for every cell you have in your tableView.
This is for example needed to calculate the size of the scrollView that houses the cells.

But since the creation of the cell follows a specific algorithm that was created by you, you should be able to figure out the height of each cell before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

Use the same parts of the code that determine the height of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and put them into heightForRowAtIndexPath:
Optimization is important for heightForRowAtIndexPath because it's called for every cell. So make sure you only do the minimum amount of work that's necessary to calculate the height.

Answer (score -1):

What about forcing an extra call to heightForRowAtIndexPath inside cellForRowAtIndexPath IF the height of the cell is not the one you want?

You just need to avoid an infinite loop :)

Comment: This doesn't work: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called by the UITableView before `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to set up the row heights. Calling `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` simply calculates the cell height and returns it—it doesn't have any effect on the tableView cells that have been set up already.

Comment: Well... If you set the height on a certain row to be something else than the other ones, it will be when the cell is retrieved moments later...

So... If one changes the specified height of a certain row in cellForRowAtIndexPath, then, the next time heightForRowAtIndexPath is called, it will be changed...